# How to get users' own data from a collection?

Tags: authentication, graphql, directus

**How to get users' own data from a collection?**

After a successful login, `/auth/login` does not return user-related info except the Bearer token.

So **how do I request only the logged-in users' data** from a collection?

While using GraphQL I can filter my result by this way if I knew my user ID. But I don't think it's the best way.

> (filter:{user_created:{id:{_eq: "59d5bc57-6a67-4200-b435-553403c5b503"} }})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the docs. :)

https://docs.directus.io/reference/api/system/users/?#retrieve-the-current-user

The endpoint "`${api_url}/users/me`" will return the information for the currently authenticated user. You should be able to map this to GQL as you need.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with GraphQL. I will just get it with GET request and use it.

Comment: I've not really used GraphQL, however could you not try this? 
query { users { me(){} } }

Comment: there are just items and server fields under Query

Comment: There should be feature parity between the REST API and the GraphQL endpoint — if one is missing something, just open a ticket on GitHub and it will get resolved.

Comment: Using GraphQL is totally ok by now. See my reply querying `users_me` on the system endpoint

Answer (score 0):

Directus allows you to call the current user via the GraphQL query to `/graphql/system`:

```
query me {
    users_me {
        id
    }
}
```

This retrieves the id and you can add the fields you need.

It is compatible with the Directus SDK if you're using it.