# How to get Directus user data using GraphQL?

Tags: directus

### Is it possible to request Directus users' data using GraphQL query?

Even I have correct permissions, there are just two fields under query type.

[image: fields]

Comment: Are you looking for Directus User data, or data in your own `user` Collection? What query are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, If you are just using **GraphQL** endpoint then it's **not possible to get user data**.

But you can use REST API instead of GraphQL. You can get user data using `GET /users/me`

[Check similar StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66134948/11993949)

Comment: This is answer is no longer correct

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with the latest version (v9.5.0).
The [documentation](https://docs.directus.io/reference/introduction/#rest-vs-graphql) says there’s feature parity between REST and GraphQL API.

Make sure to allow at a minimum read permissions for the ID in:
`Systems Collections` / `Directus Users`

Also you’ll need to authenticate e.g. with an authorization token in the http headers:

```
{
 "authorization": "Bearer YOUR_TOKEN_HERE"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from version 11 (Beta in August 2023) and using the [JS SDK](https://github.com/directus/sdk):

```js
const directus = createDirectus('https://api.example.com')
  .with(graphql())
  .with(authentication())

await api.login('me@example.com', 'mys3kr3t')
  
directus.query(`query me {
    users_me {
        id
    }
}
`, {}, 'system')
```

Will retrieve the current user's id.
Of course you can retrieve all other fields.

[Details here](https://github.com/directus/sdk/issues/159)

Note that version 11 is currently in Beta when writing this, some syntax might change in Directus SDK in the meantime.